# How to remove the extra zeros from the output?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem from CodeChef. The problem statement is as follows.

> Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal, the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.
>
> Input:
> 42 120.00
>
> Output:
> 120.00

For this input, I am getting an output of 120.000.00.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int withdraw;
    float initial_balance, final_balance;
    scanf("%d %f", &withdraw, &initial_balance);
    if(withdraw % 5 == 0)
        {
            final_balance = initial_balance - withdraw - 0.50;
        }
    else
    {
        printf("%.2f", initial_balance);
    }
    printf("%.2f", final_balance);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By removing lines to print such extra things? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You'll need to show us how you're getting the extra zeros for us to be able to tell you how to avoid them.

Comment: Please add the code you have at the moment. Otherwise it's almost impossible to find the problem.

Comment: After running the code, I gave the inputs in a single line and I am getting that output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `120.00` via `printf("%.2f", initial_balance);` and after that printing uninitialized indeterminate value via `printf("%.2f", final_balance);`.

Instead of the printing `printf("%.2f", initial_balance);` in the `if` statement, you should set the answer to `final_balance` like `final_balance = initial_balance;`.